# Does the HERE API provide triangulation of GSM cell info?

Tags: here-api

Currently testing out the HERE API for use in a GSM positioning application. It appears that no cell triangulation occurs but then why is it possible to pass several GSM data points into the API?

I have tried passing up to 7 GSM cell positions but the estimated location always ends up on one of the cells and not close to the actual position of the device.

```py
###############################################################################
# cell tower info for HERE API
###############################################################################
here_cell_0 = {"cid": 17078,
          "lac": 314,
          "mcc": 234,
          "mnc": 15,
          "rxlevel": -52,
          "nmr": [{"bsic": 18, "bcch": 25, "rxlevel": -52}]}

here_cell_1 = {"cid": 13491,
          "lac": 165,
          "mcc": 234,
          "mnc": 15,
          "rxlevel": -61,
          "nmr": [{"bsic": 27, "bcch": 33, "rxlevel": -61}]}

here_cell_2 = {"cid": 16191,
          "lac": 316,
          "mcc": 234,
          "mnc": 15,
          "rxlevel": -62,
          "nmr": [{"bsic": 38, "bcch": 26, "rxlevel": -62}]}

here_cell_3 = {"cid": 13492,
          "lac": 165,
          "mcc": 234,
          "mnc": 15,
          "rxlevel": -65,
          "nmr": [{"bsic": 8, "bcch": 30, "rxlevel": -65}]}

here_cell_4 = {"cid": 18119,
          "lac": 316,
          "mcc": 234,
          "mnc": 15,
          "rxlevel": -65,
          "nmr": [{"bsic": 35, "bcch": 36, "rxlevel": -65}]}

here_cell_5 = {"cid": 13564,

          "lac": 165,
          "mcc": 234,
          "mnc": 15,
          "rxlevel": -66,
          "nmr": [{"bsic": 37, "bcch": 29, "rxlevel": -66}]}

here_cell_6 = {"cid": 17079,
          "lac": 314,
          "mcc": 234,
          "mnc": 15,
          "rxlevel": -69,
          "nmr": [{"bsic": 41, "bcch": 37, "rxlevel": -69}]}

ALL_CELLS_HERE = [here_cell_0,here_cell_1,here_cell_2,here_cell_3,here_cell_4,here_cell_5,here_cell_6]

###############################################################################
# HERE API data
###############################################################################
# API KEY
APP_ID = ""
APP_CODE = ""
APP_ID_RESOURCE = "app_id=" + APP_ID
APP_CODE_RESOURCE = "app_code=" + APP_CODE

# position API
POS_BASE_URL = "https://pos.api.here.com/positioning/v1/locate"
POS_URL = POS_BASE_URL + "?" + APP_ID_RESOURCE + "&" + APP_CODE_RESOURCE

###############################################################################
# get positions of cells and estimated position
###############################################################################
CELL_COORDINATES = []

# get cell tower postions
for CELL in ALL_CELLS_HERE:
    POST_BODY = {"gsm": [CELL]}
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(url = POS_URL, json = POST_BODY, headers=headers)
    if( r.status_code == 200):
        data = r.json()
        print(data)
        CELL_COORDINATES.append(data)
    else:
        print("Request failed, status code: " + str(r.status_code) )

# get estimated position HERE API
POST_BODY = {"gsm": ALL_CELLS_HERE}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url = POS_URL, json = POST_BODY, headers=headers)
if( r.status_code == 200):
    ESTIMATED_COORDINATE_HERE_API = r.json()
    print(ESTIMATED_COORDINATE_HERE_API)
else:
    print("Request failed, status code: " + str(r.status_code) )
```

This is currently how i am calling the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are listing neighboring cells wrong. They should be after main cell inside "nmr". If your serving (main) cell is 17078 format should be following:

```
{
  "gsm": [{
  "mcc": 234,
  "mnc": 15,
  "lac": 314,
  "cid": 17078,
  "rxlevel": -52,
  "nmr": [
    {"bsic": 27, "bcch": 33, "rxlevel": -61,"lac":165,"cid":13491},
    {"bsic": 38, "bcch": 26, "rxlevel": -62,"lac":316,"cid":16191},
    {"bsic": 8, "bcch": 30, "rxlevel": -65,"lac":165,"cid":13492},
    {"bsic": 35, "bcch": 36, "rxlevel": -65,"lac":316,"cid":18119},
    {"bsic": 37, "bcch": 29, "rxlevel": -66,"lac":165,"cid":13564},
    {"bsic": 41, "bcch": 37, "rxlevel": -69,"lac":314,"cid":17079}
  ]
  }]
}
```

Format is listed [here](https://here.intersolute.de/services/files/here-platform-news/2018/release-notification-2018-01-d88/HERE%20Tracking%20v1.0%20Developers%20Guide.pdf)